# What is wrong in my friend assembly example during compilation using csc.exe?

Tags: c#, .net

I have made a simple example with **friend assemblies** in C#.

This is the code for the AssemblyA.dll:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly:InternalsVisibleToAttribute("AssemblyB")]
internal class Claseinternal
{
    internal void MetodoUno()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MetodoUno");
    }

    private void MetodoDos()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MetodoDos");
    }
}

public class ClasePublica
{
    private void MetodoTres()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MetodoTres");
    }

    internal void MetodoCuatro()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MetodoCuatro");
    }

    private void MetodoCinco()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MetodoCinco");
    }
}
```

I compile it:

```
csc /target:library AssemblyA.cs
```

By other hand, this is the AssemblyB.dll:

```
using System;

public class ClaseFriend
{
    public void MetodoPrueba()
    {
        ClasePublica cp = new ClasePublica();
        Claseinternal ci = new Claseinternal();

        ci.MetodoUno();
        ci.MetodoDos();

        cp.MetodoTres();
        cp.MetodoCuatro();
        cp.MetodoCinco();
    }
}
```

Compiling:

```
csc /target:library /reference:AssemblyA.dll AssemblyB.cs
```

And it generates the following error:

[image: error during compilation of a library]

What is wrong my code example in C#, or with the compiler parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a difficulty when building with csc directly. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx):

> When you compile an assembly (assembly AssemblyB) that will access internal types or internal members of another assembly (assembly A), you must explicitly specify the name of the output file (.exe or .dll) by using the /out compiler option. This is required because the compiler has not yet generated the name for the assembly it is building at the time it is binding to external references. For more information, see /out (C#) and /out (Visual Basic).

You have not used the /out flag. I believe you need the command lines:

```
csc /target:library /out:AssemblyA.dll AssemblyA.cs 
csc /target:library /reference:AssemblyA.dll /out:AssemblyB.dll AssemblyB.cs
```

It is easier if you use Visual Studio, which will handle this automatically.

Comment: I like it to write using plain text code editor (Notepad++).

Correction:

csc /target:library /out:AssemblyA.dll AssemblyA.cs

csc /target:library /reference:AssemblyA.dll /out:AssemblyB.dll AssemblyA.cs

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez Ok fixed. You might be interested in [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) if you don't want to use C# in a heavy-weight environment like VS.